# Autosubmit ReactJS form as soon as it is created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Is there any way of autosubmitting a form as soon as it is created? I have a component `<ShowVideo />`. Inside this component, I'm dispatching an action which will give some `hidden field` and `signatures`. Afterwards, I'm rendering this form on the page. What I want is to submit this form dynamically once my form is rendered. There can be multiple forms.

One approach which came to my mind was to call another function `handleSubmit` after `form` tag, which will have `form.submit()` method inside it but how will I make sure that the entire form is rendered or not.

```
class ShowVideo extends Component {
  render() {
    let renderInputFields = null
    if (this.props.videoData.data.hasOwnProperty("signature")) {
      renderInputFields = Object.keys(launchData).map((key, i) => {
        return (<input type="hidden" name={key} key={i} value={launchData[key]} />)
      })
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe width="100%" height="430px" frameBorder="0" name="videoIframe"></iframe>
        <form name="ltiLaunchForm" id="ltiLaunchForm" method="post" target="target_iframe" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action={launchUrl}>
          {renderInputFields}
          <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value={signature} />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to auto submit the form after it's been created but the form has some of its elements rendered later, then i recommend adding a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function that will dynamically trigger after a new rerender.

In this function we will detect if the rerender has rendered all of the form elements. If so, then we can programmatically trigger the form submit.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const formElementKey1Exists = document.getElementById("element1");
    const formElementKey2Exists = document.getElementById("element2");
    ...
    if (formElementKey1Exists  && formElementKey2Exists && ...) {
        document.getElementById('ltiLaunchForm').submit();
    }
}
```

The conditional will ensure your entire form is rendered before dynamically submitting.

Answer (score 10):

A more contemporary solution (using React Hooks) might look like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const AutoSubmitForm = ({
  actionUrl,
  params
}) => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    formRef.current.submit();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} method="POST" action={actionUrl}>
      {Object.keys(params).map(name => (
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name={name}
          value={params[name]}
        ></input>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```